# passing event.target.getAttribute() to data in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML code:

```
<img src="images/website/image.svg" alt="" width="150px" height="150px" v-on:click="submitimage($event)">
```

and want to pass the src url of the image to data passing it through $event to a Vue method.

vue script code:

```
<script>
export default {
     
    data(){
        return {
            imgurl: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitimage(event){    
        var element = event.target;
        var id = element.getAttribute('src');
        window.console.log(id)
        this.imgurl = id
      
        }, 

    },

}
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
methods: {
        submitimage(event){    
        this.imgurl = this.event.target.getAttribute('src');
        window.console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'))
        
      
        },
```

But it works with window.console.log and shows the correct URL, but if I try it to pass it to data(), its not working.
No error, its just empty or undefined.
What am I missing?

Comment: What vuejs version are you using?

Comment: this seems to work fine => https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tu7vzx

Comment: where are you trying to pick up this.imgurl ?

Comment: Vue3., thats weird, if I tried to console.log this.imgurl it shows it as well. But when I am checking data at Vie Inspector in chrome, it shows empty. Never happened to me. That behaviour is weird.

Comment: OK, I restarted chrome and it works. I am so sorry, it works now. I didnt understand why it doesnt work and seems chrome was bugged. thanks again for your help. really appreciate it

Comment: feel free to accept my answer :-)

Comment: done dont understand what happened now :D

Comment: You just marked my answer as being correct to have solved your problem, and most of the time nobody else will waste time on resolved questions

Comment: It just means, the problem is solved and shows the community that it can look at other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like everything your are doing is correct:

check this stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tu7vzx

So I guess it is really the question how you are trying to access `this.imgurl`

However, your question does not show enough code to make an educated guess.